# Lines not being pushed into github

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, repository, push

I started learning git yesterday, please bear with me.
I am trying to "push" code from Visual Studio Code into Github. The commit is happening, and the file is showing up in my repository, but they are just empty (the code i typed in VS Code is not showing up in Github).

I created a repository on Github, copied the https code and cloned it onto my desktop (local), and opened it in terminal with [<xyzaddressofrepositry> code .], which opens up VSCode.

I then created a doc, and edited it (my repository name is PersonalWeb). Now I have this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PersonalWeb</h1>
    <p>Lorem Lorem1</p>
    <p>Lorem Lorem2</p>
    <p>Lorem Lorem3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then i opened terminal (In VSCode) and put in these:

```
git status #ensure it is in main branch
git add .
git commit -m initialcommit
git push origin main
```

It pushes into my github repository on my website, but the lines (as pasted above from doc) dont come up (photo attached).

Comment: I think you've forgotten an attachment. Still, more details please.  Can you show the list of commits locally as well as on GitHub?

Comment: You can list your local commits with `git log`. You can view the first commit with `git show HEAD`. If you don't see any lines in the file you committed, maybe you just forgot to save it before commiting?

Comment: And to get a nice overview of all branches and all commits run the command `gitk --alll &`. That will start a graphical program that display all of your history.